# get data from nested documents in mongodb / find is not working

Tags: mongodb, nested, find, documents

i have data in my collection called users like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeffdb80e006205640052ff"),
    "name" : "KOTA AMBON",
    "email" : "ambon@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2y$10$VVaGAVniUbgBnDw6x5yZ0uAvJDGa5ekmVPJk/1Lubz5yKzZ75opo2",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-07T07:18:16Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-07T07:18:16Z"),
    "dinas" : [
            {
                    "id" : "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e00620564005307",
                    "nama_dinas" : "dinas perikanan",
                    "deskripsi_dinas" : "dinas untuk ikan",
                    "keyword" : "ikan"
            },
            {
                    "id" : "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af010390e00620564005308",
                    "nama_dinas" : "dinas perhubungan",
                    "deskripsi_dinas" : "dinas untuk hubungan",
                    "keyword" : "jalan"
            }
    ]
```

}

I want to get `dinas` attribute where `id` is  `"5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e00620564005307"

I had using function `db.users.find('dinas.id', '5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e00620564005307')` but the output still called all elements in `dinas` like i wrote above.

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: What is exactly your expected output? Do you want to search dinas or users?

Comment: I want to get users that only has dinas where id is "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e00620564005307"

can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering in MongoDB (using `find`) will always return entire document, you have to add projection as a second argument of a `find` method like below:

```
db.users.find({"dinas.id": "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e00620564005307"},
{ "dinas": { $elemMatch: { id: "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e00620564005307" } } });
```

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) in projection will filter your nested array and return first matching element (that's fine assuming your ids are unique)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Comment: I'm sorry I have question again. What if i want to get dinas where id is "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e006205640053078" ? I try using that code, but it didn't give output

Comment: @NodyRiskyPratomo just to clarify: first argument of find method checks if any item in dinas has specified id and returns entire document, second argument filters nested array and returns first matching element. Did you try: `db.users.find({"dinas.id": "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e006205640053078"},
{ "dinas": { $elemMatch: { id: "5aeffdb80e006205640052ff_5af0101d0e006205640053078" } } });`

Comment: Eh.. seems like i had typo on my query. so it didn't give me back the output hehe. Your code is works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at [array querying](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/). The problem is that your `dinas` is a array of objects, and you're trying to query it as a object directly.

Probably [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) will help you. Something like:

```
db.users.find({
    dinas: {
        $elemMatch: {
            id: 'youridhere'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just try this but it didn't work. the output still called all member in dinas

Comment: @thepanuto query will never reshape source document, $elemMatch is just a way of checking if entire document matches specified condition